# Autenticação com Symfony. Como fazer a autenticação (simples)

Tags: php, autenticação, symfony3

tenho um problema aqui.

Estou em um projeto usando o symfony (muito bom o Framework), porem tenho visto algumas complexidades de como ele faz a autenticação. Consegui fazer o login, porem na hora de entrar na home, como ela esta protegida no arquivo de segirança para apenas o ROLE_ADMIN acessar, gostaria de saber dos senhores, no symfony3, como faço para recuperar esta permissão para o meu usuário, o usuario já tem as implementações todas, porem o symfony não o ve como ROLE_ADMIN. Segue o código.

Controller

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
  if ($request->get('usuario')) {
    $usuario = $request->get('usuario');
    $senha = $request->get('senha');

    $user_manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Usuarios');
    $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');

    $user = $user_manager->loadUserByUsername($usuario);
    $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
    $salt = $user->getSalt();

    if($encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $senha, $salt)) {
      return $this->redirect('/home');
    }
    else {
      $this->addFlash('error', 'Usuario ou senha não não encontrados!');
      return $this->redirect('/');
    }
  }

  $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
  $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
  $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

  return $this->render(
      'login/index.html.twig',
      array(
          'last_username' => $lastUsername,
          'error'         => $error,
      )
  );
}
```

Repository

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.usulogin = :usulogin')
            ->setParameter('usulogin', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

        if (null === $user) {
            $message = sprintf(
                'Unable to find an active admin AppBundle:User object identified by "%s".',
                $username
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message);
        }

        return $user;
    }
}
```

Entity

```
class Usuarios implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
   //codigos não coloquei a classe interira, apenas a implemetação da interface, para ficar menor, porem garanto estar de acordo com a doc.
/**
* inicio das implementações da inteface
*/
public function getUsername()
   {
       return $this->usunom;
   }

   public function getRoles()
   {
       return array('ROLE_ADMIN');
   }

   public function getPassword()
   {
    return  $this->ususenha;
   }
   public function getSalt()
   {
     return null;
   }
   public function eraseCredentials()
   {
   }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->usuid,
            $this->usunom,
            $this->ususenha,
            // ver la sección salt debajo
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
          $this->usuid,
          $this->usunom,
          $this->ususenha,
            // ver la sección salt debajo
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

Security.yml

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Usuarios:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Usuarios

    firewalls:
        main:
            provider: our_db_provider

            anonymous: true

            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login

            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path: /

    access_control:
      - { path: ^/home, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # ...
```

todo Help é bem vindo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido,como não obtive respostas, decidi fazer eu mesmo e na verdade é bem simples, aqui vai a resolução para os que quiserem.

Controler

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use AppBundle\Entity\Usuarios;
use AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * @Route("/",name="authentication");
   */
   public function indexAction()
   {
     $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
     $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
     $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

     return $this->render(
         'login/index.html.twig',
         array(
             'last_username' => $lastUsername,
             'error'         => $error,
         )
     );
   }

   /**
    * @Route("/login", name="login");
    */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout");
     */
     public function logoutAction()
     {
     }

}
```

Na entidade do usuário implemente esta interface

```
class Usuarios implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
* inicio das implementações
*/
public function getUsername()
   {
       return $this->usunom;
   }

   public function getRoles()
   {
       return array('ROLE_ADMIN');
   }

   public function getPassword()
   {
    return  $this->ususenha;
   }
   public function getSalt()
   {
     return null;
   }
   public function eraseCredentials()
   {
   }

    /** @see \Serializable::serialize() */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->usuid,
            $this->usunom,
            $this->ususenha,
            // ver la sección salt debajo
            // $this->salt,
        ));
    }

    /** @see \Serializable::unserialize() */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        list (
          $this->usuid,
          $this->usunom,
          $this->ususenha,
            // ver la sección salt debajo
            // $this->salt
        ) = unserialize($serialized);
    }
}
```

Crie uma pasta dentro do seu Bundle chamada Repository e cria a seguinte classe dentro dela

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Security\User\UserLoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements UserLoaderInterface
{
    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        $user = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.usulogin = :usulogin')
            ->setParameter('usulogin', $username)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();

        if (null === $user) {
            $message = sprintf(
                "Usuário $username, não foi encontrado!"
            );
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException($message);
        }

        return $user;
    }
}

 ?>
```

Crie uma pasta dentro do seu Bundle chamada Security e cria a seguinte classe dentro dela

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class FormLoginAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    private $router;
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getPathInfo() != '/login') {
          return;
        }

        $email = $request->request->get('usuario');
        $request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);
        $password = $request->request->get('senha');

        return [
            'usulogin' => $email,
            'ususenha' => $password,
        ];
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $email = $credentials['usulogin'];

        return $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($email);
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        $plainPassword = $credentials['ususenha'];
        if ($this->encoder->isPasswordValid($user, $plainPassword)) {
            return true;
        }

        throw new BadCredentialsException('Erro ao autenticar!');
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        $url = $this->router->generate('home');

        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
       $request->getSession()->set(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);

       $url = $this->router->generate('authentication');

       return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->router->generate('authentication');
    }

    protected function getDefaultSuccessRedirectUrl()
    {
        return $this->router->generate('home');
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Agora edite o security.yml

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Usuarios:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:Usuarios

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
       dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

       main:
            anonymous: ~
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - app.form_login_authenticator
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /

            remember_me:
                secret:   '%secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path: /

    access_control:
      - { path: ^/home, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
      - { path: ^/cadastrarUsuario, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    # ...
```

e o services.yml

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    app.form_login_authenticator:
        class: AppBundle\Security\FormLoginAuthenticator
        arguments: ["@router", "@security.password_encoder"]
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in your services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # this means you cannot fetch services directly from the container via $container->get()
        # if you need to do this, you can override this setting on individual services
        public: false

    # makes classes in src/AppBundle available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    AppBundle\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/*'
        # you can exclude directories or files
        # but if a service is unused, it's removed anyway
        exclude: '../../src/AppBundle/{Entity,Repository,Tests}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure they're public
    # and have a tag that allows actions to type-hint services
    AppBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../../src/AppBundle/Controller'
        public: true
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more services, or override services that need manual wiring
    # AppBundle\Service\ExampleService:
    #     arguments:
    #         $someArgument: 'some_value'
```

E somente testar, aqui deu certinho.

Usando o security.yml e estas implementações, o proprio symphony se encarrega de fazer a segurança. Caso queiram proteger suas rotas apos o login, ou seja para não acessarem quando não estiverem logados, basta adicionar a rota no seu security.yml

```
access_control:
      - { path: ^/home, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
      - { path: ^/cadastrarUsuario, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Abraços.